# NoReverseMatch at /kitty_view Reverse for 'kitty' with arguments '(5,)' not found. Same url i have tried for another app and that is working

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

// While rendering this kitty_view I am getting this error. Exactly the same thing I have copied from another app that is working properly. Kindly help. Exactly same thing is working for some other app.

view.py
        ------------------
        def kitty_view(request):
            kitty_list = kitty.objects.all().order_by('-cretime')
            code1 = str(request.GET.get('Code'))
            name1 = str(request.GET.get('nam'))
            status1 = str(request.GET.get('stat'))
            if (name1 is not None and name1 != ''):
                kitty_list = kitty_list.filter(name=name1)
            if (code1 is not None and code1 != ''):
                kitty_list = kitty_list.filter(code='K00001')
            if (status1 is not None and status1 != ''):
                kitty_list = kitty_list.filter(status =  'A')
            ctx = {'kitty': kitty_list}
            return render(request, 'kitty/kitty_view.html', ctx)

```
    Url.py
    -----
    urlpatterns = [
        path('',views.index,name='index'),
        path('kitty_view',views.kitty_view,name='kitty_view')      
    ] 

    template
    ---------
    <form class="form-signin" action="{% url 'kitty_view' %}" method="get">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-row">

            <div class="mb-3">
                <select class="custom-select center-block" name="code" id="code">
                    <option value="">Choose Kitty...</option>
                    <!-- <option>{{ kitty1.code }}</option>
                    {% for i in kitty1 %}
                    <option value="{{ i.code }}"> {{ i.code|add:' - '|add:i.name }} </option>
                    {% endfor %} -->
                    <option>K00004</option>
                    <option>K00005</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <input type="text" name="nam" id="nam" class="form-control-sm center-block" placeholder="Name" autofocus>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <select class="custom-select center-block" name="stat" id="stat" placeholder="Status">
                    <option value="">Choose Status...</option>
                    <option>A</option>
                    <option>I</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <!-- <a href="{% url 'customer_view' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role = "button">Search</a> -->
                <button type="submit" class=" btn btn-info " role="button">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <table class="table table-dark">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Kitty Code</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Type</th>
                <th scope="col">Start Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Total Months</th>
                <th scope="col">End Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Total Members</th>
                <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                <th scope="col">Installment</th>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
                <th scope="col">Details</th>
                <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                <th scope="col">Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        {% if kitty %}
        <h1>Biswajit1</h1>
        {% for i in kitty %}
        <h1>Biswajit</h1>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ i.id }} </td>
                <td>{{ i.code }} </td>
                <td>{{ i.name }} </td>
                <td>{{ i.type }} </td>
                <td>{{ i.startdate }} </td>
                <td>{{ i.noofmonths }} </td>
                <td>{{ i.enddate }} </td>
                <td>{{ i.totalmembers }} </td>
                <td>{{ i.totalamount }} </td>
                <td>{{ i.noofinstallments }} </td>

                <td>{% if i.status == 'A' %}
                    {{ 'Active' }}
                    {% else %}
                    {{ 'Inactive' }}
                    {% endif %}
                </td>                 
            </tr>    
        </tbody>    
        {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </table>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: You don't have any url in your url patterns with `name='kitty'`, so the template code `{% url 'kitty' i.id %}` is failing.

Comment: where is your view and url for this `{% url 'kitty' i.id %}`

Comment: I have commented those urls. Still it is giving the same error. Commented below llines. <td><a href="{% url 'kitty' i.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">Details</a> </td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'kitty' i.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'kitty_delete' i.id %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm confirm-delete" role="button"
                    onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete this Kitty?')">Delete</a> </td>

Comment: @Biswajit please attach this in your question not in the comment

Comment: please don't ask the same question twice

Comment: Still issue is not resolved. I wont post same question again.

Comment: By deleting these lines from the template it got solved. Being a beginner i didn't know commented lines can be an issue in django. <!-- <td><a href="{% url 'kitty' i.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">Details</a> </td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'kitty' i.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'kitty_delete' i.id %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm confirm-delete" role="button"
                    onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete this Kitty?')">Delete</a> </td>-->